# How can I correctly implement a random integer command in a Discord bot with discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, command, discord.py

I recently decided to try making a bot in Discord with discord.py. The bot itself has been successfully created and integrated into the guild, but I'm having some trouble implementing certain commands.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os
import random

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "?")

@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx): 
      await ctx.channel.send("pong")

@bot.command()
async def rand(ctx, arg1, arg2):
      await ctx.channel.send(random.randint(arg1,arg2))

bot.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

When I type "?ping" in my guild, the bot replies with "pong", but when I type "?rand a b", such that a < b, the bot does not respond. Replacing "random.randint(arg1,arg2)" with any integer or string results in the bot replying with that integer or string.

How do I correctly implement the randint() function using a bot command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert arg1 and arg2 from strings to integers before passing them to randint.